# SonataAdminBundle - own views?

Tags: php, symfony1, symfony, symfony-sonata

In Symfony 1.4, I can get controllers and views from cache and use in my project with any changes.
Is this possible with SonataAdminBundle? If yes, how?

Answer (score 0):

I don't use Sonata for a long time but there is a standard way to override any part of external Bundle — [Bundle inheritance](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/inheritance.html).